# CKEditor gem not running in production: Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ckeditor

I have no clue on what's happening here.
I'm using the `gem 'ckeditor'` in my gemfile and just followed the guide to have `//= require` in `application.js`

Everything works smoothly in `development`, but after precompiling assets I have this javascript error in `production`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'apply'
```

I would like to solve the issue but maybe someone faced it before me and can help to solve it because I have no clue on what's happening there and a javascript error seems strange because the code is the same as in development.

Does anyone managed to use CKEditor with `gem 'ckeditor'`? If yes, which version and did you face the same issue as mine? How did you solve it?

Comment: Did you add the ckeditor models to the autoload array AND did you mount the engine in your routes?

Comment: I mounted the engine in routes, I didn't add ckeditor models to the autoload array: how to do it? It's not mentioned in installation process. Anyway, notice that in development mode is working.

Comment: Add this to your `config/application.rb`: `config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/models/ckeditor)` -- it is actually mentioned in the README, but it's positioned in such a way that it looks like part of the Mongoid instructions.

Comment: You are right it's hidden. I added it but it didn't change anything in any case. There is still the same javascript error, you can view it by yourself: http://bec.firedragon.webfactional.com/admin/news/new username: test@test.test password: test

Comment: Yeah, this is really weird. I'm using the latest version of the ckeditor gem in production with no problems at all. I would suggest you remove every single piece of JavaScript from your application.js and add them back one by one until you can locate the error.

Comment: You are right, I've just made an empty project and it's working. I'm trying to find out what's creating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what's causing the issue, I had an old uglifier version in my gemfile.

```
gem 'uglifier', '~> 1.0.3'
```

Updating it to:

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

Which updated it to `2.1.1`, solved the issue.